Image Augmentation for Leaf Disease Detection: Training or Testing?
I am working on a leaf disease detection project and evaluating different strategies for augmenting the existing dataset to improve model performance. However, I am facing some confusion. Should I augment only the training dataset, or should I also augment the test dataset?
For instance, I split the dataset into 5 folds for cross-validation and use a Generative Adversarial Network (GAN) for synthetic data generation. When using folds 1, 2, 3, and 4 for training and fold 5 for testing, should I augment fold 5 as well?

From my personal knowledge, you should only ever augment the training subset. The idea behind a test subset is to use it to evaluate the model's generalization capability/performance (i.e. it tries to imitate "real" data).
By using augmentation methods to increase the size of your test subset you're potentially creating a data leakage. This will cause an overestimation of the model's performance (i.e. results will look better than they actually are).
This knowledge extends to the Cross-validation training-test folds as well.
